# Duvidas sobre autenticação para aplicação Java com Spring Security (stateless)

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-security, oauth2

Vou iniciar um novo projeto e veio a duvida com relação a melhor forma de trabalhar a parte de autenticação/autorização. O projeto será desenvolvido em java com spring (spring boot), backend e frontend (angular) serão separados com possiblidade de desenvolver no futuro um aplicativo (mobile). Em resumo minhas duvidas são as seguintes:

- qual tecnologia/protocolo utilizar na API para servir uma aplicação web e mobile de forma segura? Oauth 2 + JWT?
- Implementar apenas com spring security ou usar outras tecnologias?

Ja desenvolvi aplicações com spring security usando o modulo Oauth 2 + JWT, porém pesquisando agora vi que o spring security esta descontinuando o suporte ao Authorization Server, recomendando usar "modulos" externos. Em outra pesquisa vi que a pedidos da comunidade estão desenvolvendo um Authorization Server separado (https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server). Fiquei meio perdido com essas informações.

Meu objetivo não é receber codigos prontos, apenas uma orientação sobre tecnologias e melhores praticas com as tecnologias informadas.

Desde já obrigado.